# Is there a way to create a lighting effect like this?

Tags: lighting

Im trying to recreate something like the image attached. ideally the light shining through would look more intense like rays or beams of light. Any help is appreciated[image]. Thanks!

Comment: you can try creating a plane with some transparency (alpha) with a hole with the shape of the text and put it in front of the camera. The holes will let pass the light while  the other part will block the light giving the effect you are looking for. check this file: https://pasteall.org/blend/6256aa50319b4daebe897f9f24b3cbc9

Answer (score 2):

You can get something like this:

[image]

with Cycles:

Two planes with these material setups:

front plane:

[image]

back plane:

[image]

The front plane is cut by a text -> convert to mesh.

alternative setup (EEVEE):

just compositor changes:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Seems simple enough! Ill try it and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome